# Does U-Boot operate with any BDM's that are currently (2017) sold?

Tags: u-boot

The U-Boot docs/website makes frequent references to BDI2000. I have used the BDI300 from Abatron in the past. Now I see that they have passed their EOL (end of life) and supposedly Abatron no longer is in business. How are people continuing? U-Boot is still a thing? Right?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few answers here.  First, JTAG debugging just isn't as popular as it used to be.  By and large board bring up (outside of silicon vendors) gets past the "I need a JTAG" stage almost immediately.  Second, any JTAG that supports your SoC can be used.  I personally have (but seldom use) several different inexpensive FTDI-based JTAG units.  I know others use the various more expensive JTAG units that exist.